# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

i am using core data in my application.

i am getting this error when using transformable attribute to store NSArray.

in short i want to know, what should i do to store NSArray into core data.

and how to retrive it.

this is my code.

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class category;

@interface qrandom :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* arr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) category * cid;

@end
```

...........................................................................................

```
#import "qrandom.h"

#import "category.h"

@implementation qrandom 

@dynamic arr;
@dynamic cid;

@end
```

...................................................................

category.h file

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class qrandom;

@interface category :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) qrandom * randomrelation;

@end
```

....................................................................................

category.m file

```
#import "category.h"
#import "qrandom.h"

@implementation category

@dynamic cid;
@dynamic randomrelation;

@end
```

................................................................................

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete contents of the error message? your question really doesn't have enough information to provide a helpful answer. What doesn't a to-many relationship suffice for storing the elements of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically directly storing an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary` as a transformable attribute won't work in CoreData because it will be unable to retrieve the array's values.

See Marcus's answer which suggests just using relationships:

[NSMutableArray stored with core data = WORKS, but after changing array DOESN'T WORK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426557/nsmutablearray-stored-with-core-data-works-but-after-changing-array-doesnt-w)

BUT!

You can archive your array so that it CAN be used in your managed object. See jbrennan's response here: 
[Saving an NSMutableArray to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104075/saving-an-nsmutablearray-to-core-data)